# How to get multiple key values pair under array of object through form data submition

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, form-data

I have a form data where I used the loop to generate the input type text fields.

So with the help of loop, when I open the form data through inspect element, i got something like this:

```
< input type="text" name="position1" />
< input type="text" name="position2" />
< input type="text" name="position3" />
< input type="text" name="position4" />
```

when I submit the form, On Node.js when I fetch the request through request.body i got something like this:

```
{
      position1: '1',
      position2: '2',
      position3: '3',
      position4: '4'
}
```

what I am looking is like

```
[
 {position1: '1'},
 {position2: '2'},
 {position3: '3'},
 {position4: '4'},
]
```

so that I used the map function to update the value one by one on mongodb or use the bulkwrite function to update all at once.

I tried to put [] before the value on name="". Like this name="[]position1" but not getting success.

Is there any one who can guide me on this.

Comment: You can do something like . var arr =   [{
      position1: '1',
      position2: '2',
      position3: '3',
      position4: '4'
}]

Comment: `Object.keys(theRequestBody)` of what you have currently would return you an array of all the keys.  You could loop over that, instead of changing up your data model

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi can you elaborate it please. In your answer I am not getting what you are trying to guide me. I know array of objects handling. My question is if I send the value under loop in form data then on server side I got the single objects with multiple values. How to segregate this from single object to multiple objects under an array

Comment: @Taplar it return the array with multiple values

Comment: `console.log(Object.keys({position1: '1',position2: '2',position3: '3',position4: '4'}))` in your browser console.  It returns an array of the key names.  You said in your OP you want to convert it to your second form so you could loop over them.  You can loop over that generated array of keys and access each property in the original object one at a time, without having to change the data structure of the input object.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a collection/array, you could generate the form as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="positions[]" />
<input type="text" name="positions[]" />
<input type="text" name="positions[]" />
<input type="text" name="positions[]" />
```

In node js/server side you could expect your data in `req.body.positions` like this

```
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4
]
```

If the suffix or number at the end of the name is something you would like to keep, you could consider transforming your data eg

```
var transformedPositions = req.body.positions.map(function(positionValue,index){
   var newKeyName = "position"+(index+1);
   return {newKeyName:positionValue}
})
```

which would then give you this in `transformedPositions`

```
[
 {position1: '1'},
 {position2: '2'},
 {position3: '3'},
 {position4: '4'},
]
```